# “blocked by CORS policy” error with https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0 endpoint

Tags: http, vue.js, axios, twitch

I want to send a test donation from my fronted web app. For this i use:

1. STREAMLABS API [docs](https://dev.streamlabs.com/v1.0/reference#donations-1).
2. Vue v2.5.17 component with template:

```html
<template>
 <layout>
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
   <p><label for="donationSum">Sum</label></p>
   <p><input type="number" id="donationSum" v-model="amount"></p>
   <button @click="makeDonation">DONATE</button>
 </layout>
</template>
```

'makeDonation' is mapped action from Vuex:

```js
makeDonation ({ getters }) {
  const url = 'https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/donations'
  const postData = JSON.stringify({
    name: 'TEST',
    identifier: 'TEST',
    amount: 100.00,
    currency: 'RUB',
    access_token: getters.streamlabsAccessToken
  })

  axios.post(url, postData)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      console.log(error.response)
    })
}
```

I am absolutely sure that I have the valid `access_token`, but I get an error 400:

```
POST https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/donations 400
 {...}
POST https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/donations 400
 {...}
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/donations' from 
origin 'http://192.168.39.27:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Error: Network Error
  at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:87)
undefined
```

This is normal server behavior. If something is wrong in the request, it gives 400 or 401 error, but there is a problem.
I can not get access to the body of the error, to understand what is wrong. Axios `error.response` is `undefind` and `error` has no useful information.

Screenshots:

1. [Google Chrome 71.0.3578.80 x64 console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lotcR.jpg)
2. [Google Chrome 71.0.3578.80 x64 request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SttC.jpg)

Meanwhile Postman with the same `postData` makes a valid request and returns 200 response. If I corrupt the request (delete the `access_token`, for example), then it returns informative error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."
}
```

**The big question**: how do I get access to the body of the error that the STREAMLABS server returns?

Comment: why are you using `JSON.stringify...`?

Comment: It helps to avoid OPTIONS request before POST cause formats data in correct format and axios automatically add `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header

Comment: usually i send an object as second parameter in axios call, i understand that `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will parse the string sent again?

Comment: By default axios encoded js objects as JSON and it requires an OPTIONS request cause `Content-Type: application/json` POST header. If I remove this encoding, I will get an 204 answer with the same global result: CORS error on OPTIONS request.

Comment: To reproduce the error, you can execute the following simple code in any Vue component.
`axios.get('https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/donations?access_token=AAA').then(r => { console.info(r)  }).catch(e => { console.info(e) })`

And open [the same link](https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/donations?access_token=AAA) in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the error you're experiencing doesn't have anything to do with Axios or Vue. The reason the request is failing is that you're making it inside a browser: Browsers, at least nowadays, have pretty strict rules on what requests they allow and what requests they block.

> I can not get access to the body of the error, to understand what is wrong. Axios `error.response` is `undefined` and `error` has no useful information.

That's because your browser is not **allowed** to show this information to you (or, to be more precise, the script you wrote). That's because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). CORS makes sure that scripts can only interact with things that reside on their *origin* (the domain they're coming from) *or* sites that explicitly allow *resource sharing* (the *RS* in *CORS*). Streamlabs has simply not configured resource sharing for their API (I'll get to why in a second).

So why does your request work in Postman? Because Postman isn't a browser and doesn't care about CORS. Does that mean you can't use the Streamlabs API in your app? Not necessarily, you just have to do it on the server side because your server isn't a browser. This also has the benefit that you don't expose your access token to your users (which might be the reason why Streamlabs has not configured RS).

Comment: It sounds very reasonable and generally repeats the information that can be found. Only the fact that the [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710098/no-axios-errror-response-in-vue-js-with-streamlabs-api/53712221#comment94276024_53710098) request also fails in axios and works normally in the browser does not give me peace of mind.

Comment: You were right. I checked the same endpoint with valid `access_token` and it also gave an error. Request to another endpoint (`/user`) from the same place in the code works correctly. Probably STREAMLABS does not have a global setting of CORS, but an individual for each endpoint. Crazy.

Comment: Meanwhile browser can show me information about error and axios not. Why?

Comment: The reason the request "works normally in the browser" is that when you enter the URL in your browser you will visit that resource directly on the origin (`streamlabs.com`). The browser will allow that because it trusts you (and doesn't trust scripts on the other hand). When your app is making the request, it will do that from its own origin (`yourapp.example.com`) which causes the CORS error.